# How to guarantee an r function would return an object if it exits for whatever reason?

Tags: r

There is an object that must be returned by a function regardless of why it terminated.

For example, while that function is running I press the red button on the top right corner of Rstudio to force it to terminate. In this situation, the function should return the object as well.

I remember there being something like a "on.exist" function that does something when a function exists. can't remember.

Comment: If you press the button, the function is always terminated, returning a value defeats some of the purposes of that red button. This cannot be done from within the function. Frankly, even with `tryCatch` outside of the function, I think the red button is going to preclude continued execution (which is required to be able to return something). Is your concern completely about the red button? Or do you have a long-running process and want to preserve what was already done, then ... that's a different question.

Comment: @r2evans Yes, the situation regarding preserving the long running process that you mentioned is also applicable.

Comment: I don't think there's an "easy" way to do that in R (nor many languages, in my experience), unless you explicitly store mid-loop (or mid-step) state of your process.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `on.exit` for that purpose but you could just write out any intermediate calculation so that if the function is halted you still have the last value calculated.  Alternately you could write it out to a file in which case you would have it even if R or the computer crashes.

```
# test function
f <- function() {
    for(i in 1:100) { 
      x <<- i
      Sys.sleep(10)
    }
    i
}

x <- NULL
x <- f()
# press red button before it finishes
x  # last value it calculated
```